# Back and Forward Navigation does not retain data In Firefox/chrome Browsers, but works fine in Safari

Tags: javascript

The scenario is, I have 2 tabs in application,
1. Patient List Tab
2. Patient Search Tab

After login to application by default first tab that is Patient list tab that will be selected,When I select 2 tab, Patient Search tab and search for a patient, I see a list of patient with a vertical scroller.
If I select a patient the application takes me to next page. When I navigate back I come back to same Patient search tab, retaining the same data and scroller position in Safari Browser.

If I do the same action on Firefox or chrome, if I navigate back I come back to default tab that is first Patient List Tab.

I use below function to navigate

```
function detailsBack() {
  var backBtn = document.getElementById("backBtn");
  if (backBtn.innerHTML == i18n.PTLST) {
    javascript:history.go(-1);
  }
}
```

Not sure about the issue. Kindly have a look and share your thoughts

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 3):

Because javascript:history.go(-1) is not valid javascript. If you'd use a proper debugger (firebug for example) you'd see an error there.

Try calling `history.go(-1)`, skipping the `javascript:` part. You only need that in a hyperlink.

Comment: Well yes, obviously. But then he potentially wouldnt know what a javascript debugger was, or why its not working here but it is in his link.

Comment: And even then you should not use it. `onclick="history.go(-1); return false` or `onclick="history.back(); return false` is preferred

Comment: `<a href="javascript:someFunction()"` will fail in browsers that have javascript disabled and partially unload the browser - if the someFunction leaves the page then that is less of a problem, `onclick="someFunction(); return false"` or the better `onclick="return someFunction()"` where the function returns false is what I suggest. Purists will add the event handler in a script in the head, which is the best method